# How to create a search query button in oracle form builder using go_block?

Tags: formbuilder, oracle9i

i have a master detail block which has course it shows course_id and call_id and displays course name.
i have another block(STUD_GRADE_VIEW_BLOCK) in the same form which displays student names and their grades for the course.
both blocks have a join relation. my query is i want to insert a course_id and click a search button and have it display all the information instead of clicking on the query button.

i tried the following code.

GO_BLOCK ('COURSE_BLOCK');
EXECUTE_QUERY;

GO_BLOCK('STUD_GRADE_VIEW_BLOCK');
EXECUTE_QUERY;

for the button to work i went to block property palette and disabled is this database block to no. and in property palette of course_id and put no in data required.

it gives me the following error:

ERROR 30416 RELATION'S MASTER BLOCK IS A CONTROL BLOCK
RELATION: FACULTY_DATABLO_STUDENT_DATABL
BLOCK: FACULTY_DATABLOCK
FORM: FACULTY_STUDENT_FORM